# Groupby a column in Dataframe and create another dataframe with grouped data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
data:

    items   status
0   jet     fail
1   car     fail
2   car     pass
3   bike    fail
4   car     fail
5   jet     fail
6   bike    pass
7   jet     fail
8   jet     fail
9   bike    pass
```

I want to group the data by `items` and create a new dataframe with the counts of each value.
Expected output:

```
df:
  unique  count  pass  fail
0    jet      4     0     4
1    car      3     1     2
2   bike      3     2     1
```

Now one method would be to get a list of unique `items` and loop on it to find the `count`, `pass` and `fail` and then combine these lists to a dataframe
But how can I do that efficiently ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for new index name, then add new column for `0 position` by [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) and last convert index to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['items'], df['status']).rename_axis(columns=None, index='unique')
df.insert(0, 'count', df.sum(axis=1))
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  unique  count  fail  pass
0   bike      3     1     2
1    car      3     2     1
2    jet      4     4     0
```

If `count` should be last column is possible use `margin` parameter and remove last row:

```
df = (pd.crosstab(df['items'], df['status'], 
                  margins=True, 
                  margins_name='count')
       .rename_axis(columns=None, index='unique')
       .iloc[:-1]
       .reset_index())
print (df)
  unique  fail  pass  count
0   bike     1     2      3
1    car     2     1      3
2    jet     4     0      4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the values separately and combine with `pd.concat` :

```
A = df.groupby("items").size().rename("count")
A
items
bike    3
car     3
jet     4
Name: count, dtype: int64

B = (
    df.groupby(["items", "status"])
    .size()
    .unstack(fill_value=0)
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
B
      fail  pass
items       
bike    1   2
car     2   1
jet     4   0


pd.concat((A, B), axis=1).reset_index()

   items    count   fail    pass
0   bike    3        1      2
1   car     3        2      1
2   jet     4        4      0
```